# Put some text in niceditor

Tags: javascript, php, html, nicedit

I got simple script that put some text in textarea:

**Javascript**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add").click(function(){
      $('#comment').html('[quote] <?php echo link_to($comment->user->username, 'profile/'.$comment->user->username); ?> written: <?php echo $comment->content; ?> [/quote]');
  });
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="comment" name="comment"></textarea><br />
```

But it's working just then I turn off `niceditor`.

**My niceditor code:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
            bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas({buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','strikeThrough','image','upload','link','unlink']} ) });

        //]]>
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using only php and nicedit you should place the php code straight inside the  tags

for example

```
<textarea id="comment" name="comment"><?php echo link_to($comment->user->username, 'profile/'.$comment->user->username); ?> written: <?php echo $comment->content; ?></textarea>
```